# SQL: How to exclude only the criteria if the 2 criteria are met and not both separately within multiple where?

Tags: sql, netezza

```
Select * 
FROM SOME_TABLE
where Variable_1 in (1,2,3,4)
and not (Variable_1 in (1) and Variable_2<75000)
```

So I want Variable 1,2,3,4 included in the output but all variable_1=1 AND <75000 excluded.
I only manage to exclude ALL Variable_1 = 1 and ALL Variable_2<75000. I only need both variable combined excluded while separately kept!

I use netezza SQL.

Comment: *I only need both variable combined excluded while separately kept!* Your query must do this strictly. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ae3a1e9b013e30bf36c00bbbdfc033f). Search for error in some another place.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you really want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Use not exists:

```
Select * 
FROM SOME_TABLE A
where Variable_1 in (1,2,3,4)
and not EXISTS 
(
 SELECT 1 FROM SOME_TABLE B WHERE 
 A.PRIMARYKEY = B.PRIMARYKEY 
 AND Variable_1 in (1) 
 and Variable_2<75000
);
```

Comment: Not needed - do the same as source query but is more complex.